# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.metrics.scorer'

Tags: scikit-learn, modulenotfounderror, eli5

I was trying to use the eli5 package in Python. Initially I was unable to install that, but later fixed it with **conda install -c conda-forge eli5**.

Now when I try to import eli5 into my Jupyter Notebbok, I get the following error:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.metrics.scorer'**.

How do I resolve this issue? I am trying to evaluate a model and use the eli5 command to give me the top 10 features.

Comment: try doing `pip install --user scikit-learn` on console in your venv and try imporring it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those of you who have tried to import something from `sklearn.metrics.scorer` and got the error **No module named 'sklearn.metrics.scorer'**, all you have to do is import the same objects from `sklearn.metrics` since the contents have been moved in the newer versions of sklearn (1.0+). List of scorers for example used to be accessible through `from sklearn.metrics.scorer import SCORERS`, but in the newer versions it is accessible through `from sklearn.metrics import SCORERS`.

And for [@Supreetha Krishna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19511264/supreetha-krishna)'s question, chances are you have had installed eli5 version 0.11.0, which according to eli5 documents is compatible with sklearn version 0.18+, alongside sklearn version 1.0+. However, the moving of the contents within `sklearn.metrics.scorer` has caused the error. You can either use pip (`pip install eli5`) to get the latest versions of eli5 (currently 0.13.0), in which this issue is resolved, or use conda to update eli5 package, since according to https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/eli5, conda currently uses version 0.13.0 of eli5 too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using `scikit-learn` version **1.3.2** and there is no module called *scorer.py*, it has changed to *_scorer.py*. Also the dict of all the scorer types has now been changed from *SCORERS* to *_SCORERS*.

So to solve your issue, the dict of scorers can be accessed via:

`from sklearn.metrics._scorer import _SCORERS`

If you just want a list of the available scorers then you can use the variable:

`from sklearn.metrics import __all__`